# How to extract children as string?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list which is an array of elements:

```
  list: [
    {
      id: '1',
      item: <div>First name</div>,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      item: <div>Last name</div>,
    },
  ],
```

Using the map function, I would like to extract the html inside each div into a string.

```
{list.map((sectionList, i) => (
                  <SelectItem
                    key={sectionList.id}
                    value={sectionList.item....}
                  >
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you really need strings, or can you pass React elements? That is, what does SelectItem do with the `value` prop?

Comment: You want to convert JSX to string? What's wrong with passing jsx to component props as in the example?

Comment: SelectItem must use that text inside JSX as string, I mean 'value' must be a string, so it's either I change the structure of the props to contain strings, or I transform it into string inside the map function

Comment: Do you want only the inner text or also the full html?

Comment: Just the inner text, thanks in advance

Comment: value={sectionList.item.props.children} will give you the inner text assuming there is no nested tags inside your div

Answer (score 0):

Change the list to :

```
 list: [
    {
      id: '1',
      item: First name,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      item: Last name
    },
  ],
```

Then pass the item using map :

```
{list.map((sectionList, i) => (
                  <SelectItem
                    key={sectionList.id}
                    value={sectionList.item}
                  >
```